# How to fix the error "Cannot find discord.js" after trying "npm install discord.js"?

Tags: javascript, module, discord, discord.js, stack

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\index.js
Process exited with code 1
Uncaught Error Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'`
```

How to fix this thing? I already tried `npm install discord.js` and `npm install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to run npm install discord.js in the root of your project directory and then save and restart your ide. Also, if you're using src attribute in html to reference your js file be sure that you have the right path.

"/someFile.js " This looks in the root of your project.

"someFile.js" This looks in the current directory where this html file resides.